# Difference between styles.xml (res\values\styles.xml) and styles.xml (res\values-v21\styles.xml)?

Tags: android, mobile, styles, android-appcompat

What is the main difference between these two files : styles.xml (res\values\styles.xml) and styles.xml (res\values-v21\styles.xml ?

For targeting old android versions, which file should we modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android will use `res\values-v21\styles.xml` if the user's device is running Android API level 21+ (Android 5.0+) & will use `res\values\styles.xml` for older versions

Comment: Does this mean I can delete my general styles.xml if I'm only targetting v21+?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the styles differ in android versions.

`styles.xml` in values-v21 mean that, that particular style is for Android API 21 version 5.0+

while `styles.xml` will be for any other Android version besides 5.0+.

its the same as language where you create an activity for en, fr, pk etc.

Older version would automatically be targetted by the `values/styles.xml` file.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. `values/styles.xml` work for **all** versions including 5.0+.